# Calling Scalar-valued Functions in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-function

I have migrated a database from oracle, and now have a few Scalar-valued Functions.

However, when I call them, I get an error saying:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.chk_mgr", or the name is ambiguous.

I'm calling it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.chk_mgr('asdf')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE` statement for the function in question?

Comment: Also, when you say that you're calling it, how/where are you calling it from? Maybe you're pointing to the wrong DB without realizing it?

Comment: I just had this issue.  @TomH's comment was the correct answer.  The top voted answer was a red herring for me since (like the question says) I was actually using a Scalar-valued function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Are you sure it's not a `Table-Valued Function`?

The reason I ask:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.chk_mgr(@mgr VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS @mgr_table TABLE (mgr_name VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN 
  INSERT @mgr_table (mgr_name) VALUES ('pointy haired boss') 
  RETURN
END 
GO

SELECT dbo.chk_mgr('asdf')
GO
```

Result:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function 
or aggregate "dbo.chk_mgr", or the name is ambiguous.
```

However...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.chk_mgr('asdf') 

mgr_name
------------------
pointy haired boss
```

Answer (score 20):

Can do the following

```
PRINT dbo.[FunctionName] ( [Parameter/Argument] )
```

E.g.:

```
PRINT dbo.StringSplit('77,54')
```

Answer (score 14):

That syntax works fine for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.test_func
(@in varchar(20))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
GO

SELECT dbo.test_func('blah')
```

Are you sure that the function exists as a function and under the dbo schema?

Comment: The SELECT * would not work for me either. The syntax above worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an inline table value function. Therefore you must use Select * From function. 
If you want to use select function() you must use a scalar function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186755%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the correct database selected. You may have the master database selected if you are trying to run it in a new query window.